# Dart await Future.wait() with vs without inner async await

Tags: dart, asynchronous, future

In Dart, given an `async` method

```
Future transformObject(T object);
```

both of the following are legal:

```
Future transformData(Iterable<T> objects) async {
    await Future.wait(objects.map((o) => transform(o));
}
```

and

```
Future transformData(Iterable<T> objects) async {
    await Future.wait(objects.map((o) async { await transform(o); });
}
```

Is there any difference betwen the two, what is it and which one should I go for if I just want to transform all data objects asynchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `transsform` returns a `Future`, then there is no meaningful difference between `transform`, `(o) => transform(o)` and `(o) async => await transform(o);`. The more wrappings you add, the more overhead, but it's basically the same.

Your function, `(o) async { await transform(o); }` doesn't return the result of the future that `transform` returns, but if you don't need that value, then it shouldn't matter. (The name does suggest the you care about the value, though.) You'll still wait for that future to *complete* before being done.

What you could (possibly should) go for:

```dart
Future<List> transformData(Iterable<T> objects) =>
    Future.wait(objects.map(transform));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll go with your suggestion. Btw, yes I don't need the return value because the transformation is done in place because the parameter type T is abstract, so I can't instantiate a T to return. I just transform fields in T that are common between all subtypes X : T, and the callers decide the subtype beforehand.